# Two-way binding with parent.parent scope

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I have an issue where a directive with an isolate scope is not making changes via binding to its parent.parent scope.

In summary, I would expect that changes made to a property in the directive's isolate scope which is bound to a parent property would propagate all the way up parent scopes for that property (the property was inherited from a parent.parent scope to begin with), but it doesn't. It only changes the value on the immediate parent scope, while the parent.parent scope has the old value. Worse, any changes to the parent.parent scope property no longer trickle down to the isolate scope or its immediate parent. I understand this is the normal behavior of Javascript's prototype inheritance which Angular scopes are built on, but it's not wanted in this case of two-way data binding and I'm looking for a solution in Angular.

Here is an example of the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/abeall/RmDuw/344/

My HTML contains a controller div (`MyController1`), in it is another controller div (`MyController2`), and in that is a directive (`MyDirective`):

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <p>MyController1: {{myMessage}} <button ng-click="change()">change</button></p>
    <div ng-controller="MyController2">
        <p>MyController2: {{myMessage}} <button ng-click="change()">change</button></p>
        <p>MyDirective: <my-directive message="myMessage"/></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript defines `myMessage` on the outer `MyController` scope, the inner `MyController2` scope inherits and binds `myMessage` to `message` on the directive, and the `MyDirective` defines `message` as an isolate scope property. At each level a `change()` function is defined which changes the local message property:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyController($scope) {
    var count = 0;
    $scope.myMessage = "from controller";
    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.myMessage = "from controller one " + (++count);
    }
}

function MyController2($scope) {
    var count = 0;
    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.myMessage = "from controller two " + (++count);
    }
}

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>Hello {{message}} <button ng-click="change()">change</button></span>',
        scope: {
            message: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            var count = 0;
            scope.change = function(){
                scope.message = "from directive " + (++count);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

What you'll notice is that:

- If you click the `MyController1`'s change button a few times, all levels are updated (it inherits downwards).
- If you then click the `MyDirective`'s change button, it updates `MyController2` (binding upward) but does not change `MyController1` in any way.
- After this point, clicking `MyController1`'s change button no longer trickles down to `MyController2` and `MyDirective` scope, and vice versa. The two are now separated from each other. This is the problem.

So my question is:

- Does Angular have a way to allow binding or inheritance of scope properties (`myMessage` in this case) to trickle all the way up parent scopes?
- If not, in what way should I sync changes in a directive's isolate scope to a parent.parent controller scope's properties? The directive can not know about the structure of its parents.

Comment: This appears to be a side effect of JavaScript Prototype Inheritance.  This is happening because you are using primitives rather than objects, and JavaScript Inheritance allows primitives to be hidden in the Prototype Chain.  I can't explain it nearly as well as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs), I recommend a thorough read.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I understand that is the problem, but is there a solution using Angular binding? If not, what other Angular solutions to this problem are there?

Comment: use an object, or use the ControllerAs syntax, where the controller is the object.  I highly recommend the ControllerAs syntax for many other reasons, but mostly because it breaks the dependence on `$scope`, helps with inheritance issues, and is much closer to the angular 2 syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with ControllerAs syntax, I'll look into this. Any examples you can point me towards?

Comment: there are a few good articles, but I'd start out with http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/.  or http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

Comment: it would be better to include the `link` code in `controler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Claies mentioned, using `controller as` is a great idea. This way you can be direct about which scope you want to update, as well as easily being able to pass scopes around in methods.

[Here is a fiddle of the results you were likely expecting](http://jsfiddle.net/owzh669L/7/)

Syntax:  `ng-controller="MyController as ctrl1"`

Then inside: `{{ctrl1.myMessage}}` or `ng-click="ctrl1.change()"` and `click="ctrl2.change(ctrl1)"`

This changes the way you write your controller by leaving out the `$scope` dependency unless you need it for other reasons then holding your model.

```
function MyController () {
  var count = 0
  this.myMessage = "from controller"
  this.change = function () {
    this.myMessage = "from controller one " + (++count)
  }
}

function MyController2 () {
  var count = 0
  this.change = function (ctrl) {
    ctrl.myMessage = "from controller two " + (++count)
  }
}
```

Comment: Definitely sold on the "controller as" syntax, this looks way better than the magical scope inheritance I've been relying on. I ended up working around it by binding to `$parent.myMessage` but this is definitely the more complete fix, and what I'll start with in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest change is using $scope.msg.mymessage instead of just $scope.msg in your root controller.

```
function MyController($scope) {
    var count = 0;
    $scope.msg = {};
    $scope.msg.myMessage = "from controller";
    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.msg.myMessage = "from controller one " + (++count);
    }
}
```

Here's a forked fiddle (that sounds funny) with the intended results.

http://jsfiddle.net/nk5cdrmx/